# Installing Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 with no internet connection

Tags: 14.04, server, internet

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 with no internet connection - and I'm going round in circles as I keep getting prompted for a mirror etc. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...... I assume all I need is packaged in the iso? The machine I'm using has 2 network cards but I don't have internet connectivity.

-Additional info.

From the Ubuntu installer main menu I have:

- Chosen a language - success
- Configured the keyboard - success
- Detected network hardware - success
- Configure the network - success (no internet connection available)
- Choose a mirror of the ubuntu archive - unsuccessful as have no internet connection
- Download installer components - can't due to no internet connection

Not sure what to do next.....
Do I have to Execute a shell and install that way and if so how?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cheers Eliah - just wondering if it can be done. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the updated info. Which iso image did you download?

Comment: ubuntu- 14.04.1 -server-amd64.iso

Comment: I think the problem is specific to 14.04 as I recall earlier Ubuntu server images had options to continue the installation when no sources were available.